# Please help in understanding technical different between CSV and XLS

Tags: csv, xls

Please help in understanding technical difference between CSV and XLS file

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/154599/difference-between-csv-and-xls-files

Comment: Thanks for reply Polak, In given URL, I did not get information about data limitation and which is better for use?

Comment: I think it depends on how good is the library that you use to handle it. The limitation could be the memory or the disk space. If you ask me, I would choose CSV, because it's as simple to read as a text file. Also it's easy to generate. I don't see any substantial improvement using xls, but I'm not an expert, it's just my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CSV file is a comma delimited ASCII text file.  It will open in Excel automatically, because it is made in such a way that Excel can easily parse and display the information in a tabular format.

An XLS file is a proprietary binary format that was discontinued a few versions ago.  The current method is a sort of "hybrid XML" file with an XLXS extension.

While it is still ASCII text at it's core, it is an XML file with a full tagged structure.

Comment: Thanks for answer friend, please provide me that who is store more no records .

Comment: Technically, there is almost no limit for a CSV file since it is just plain text.  But large file become impossible to work with.  Excel can only handle a little over 1 million records per sheet.  You have to split your data up, if it's more rows than that.

Comment: @Dhiru There is no limitation to store sizes but .XLS will be faster to open and work with compared to .CSV. Also depends on the type of data you want to store, if its plain text  , you are better of with .CSV

Comment: There is no reason that a CSV file must be ASCII. ASCII is just one possibility. When you import into Excel, it rightly requires you to say which encoding the file uses.

Answer (score 0):

CSV is a format for file that stores tabular data (numbers and text) in plain text separated by commas. Plain text means that the file is interpreted as a sequence of characters, so that it is human-readable with a standard text editor. Each line of the file is a data record. Each record consists of one or more fields, separated by commas. The use of the comma as a field separator is the source of the name for this file format.

XLS is the file extension for Microsoft Excel, it isn't an open format and it stores a lot of info, not only the tabuled data.

Microsoft Excel can import easily CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

- Description(.XLS):

This is the default file format of spreadsheets created using Microsoft Excel application. These can however be augmented by adding macros(XLSM) etc.

- Description(.CSV:

A ".CSV" file or "Comma Separated Values" file is basically a flat file similar to .txt file which has values or fields separated by commas "," .

- Usage:

These types of files are used to when you need to transmit data between systems which cannot recognise the Microsoft specific ".XLS" format. A classic example would be to send an excel or ".XLS" file to a Mainframe system you will need to convert it into a ".CSV" file by simply saving it with .CSV extension.